# VS2012 : Indentation of switch case in JavaScript when used with JSHint

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, formatting, indentation, jshint

The default indentation of Switch case in Visual Studio 2012 in JavaScript is like,

```
switch (dropdownNumber) {
    case 1:
        console.log('reset in 1');
        break;
    case 2:
        console.log('reset in 2');
        break;
    case 3:
        console.log('reset in 3');
        break;
}
```

I am using JShint to validate the JavaScript code, which screams at me saying the indentation is incorrect. It expects the `case` to align just below `switch`

Are there any editor settings which can align the switch cases as JSHint expects it to be? or is there a property in JSHint which will ignore this style of indentation?

What am I missing?

Comment: Right now, I am turning off JSHint validations before the switch case and enabling them again.

Answer (score 0):

See https://cn.eslint.org/docs/2.13.1/rules/indent#switchcase

You can use:

```
/*eslint indent: ["error", 2, { "SwitchCase": 1 }]*/
```

Or, in `.eslintrc.yml`:

```
# ...
rules:
  indent:
    - error
    - 2
    - SwitchCase: 1 # <<< Add this
# ...
```